# WCF Restful Service (Windows Auth) with JSONP

Tags: javascript, wcf, rest, jsonp

I have a WCF RESTful service using Windows Authentication set up and it's working fine. Now I want to enable it for cross-domain access so I change my js to the following:

```
$.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         url: "http://www.example.com/MyService.svc/GetData",
            contentType: "application/javascript",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {
                alert($.parseJSON(data));
            },
            error: function (ex) {
                throw ex;
            }
        });
```

In Chrome Developer's Tool, under the Network tab I can see the request has a 200 status code and in the Response tab I see the data being returned. However, in my javascript the success block never gets called. It goes into the error block with the error:

```
Uncaught #<Object>
$.ajax.error
x.Callbacks.c
x.Callbacks.p.fireWith
k
x.ajaxTransport.send.n.onload.n.onreadystatechange
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I think contentType should be "application/json; charset=utf-8".

Answer (score 0):

If changing contenttype to "application/json; charset=utf-8" does not solve the problem, then you can try below code:

If you want to enable it for cross-domain access then you should include below code in global.asax.cs file.

```
    protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   
        EnableCrossDmainAjaxCall();
    }
    private void EnableCrossDmainAjaxCall()
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
        }
    }
```

And you can write ajax call function as below code:

```
$.ajax({
        isPostBack: false,
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://www.example.com/MyService.svc/GetData",
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: '{}',
        dataType: 'json',
        crossDomain: true,
        success: function (data) {
            alert($.parseJSON(data));
        },
        error: function (ex) {
            throw ex;
        }
    });
```